# Python 3: find max elements equal to each other in list

Tags: python, list

how do I find out the maximum amount of 1s (or any element I would like) next to each other in a list?

```
l = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1]
```

In this case I would need a function that will return a 4.

Thank you.

Comment: One possible solution is to use `itertools.groupby`, and then find the group with the highest count of 1s.

Comment: Someone already provided a good answer, but I wonder what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function can be used for this:

```
import itertools

l = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1]
print(max([len(list(g))*k for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x == 1)]))
```

Comment: What happens if there are 10 adjacent `7`s? You need to filter the groups before `max`ing.

Answer (score 0):

Manually:

```
def makeMyHomework(li):
'''reads a list of int's and looks for the logest run of one int'''
    curVal = None
    curCount = 0
    maxVal = None
    maxCount = -1
    for n in l:
        if curVal == None:
            curVal = n
        if curVal == n:
            curCount +=1
        if curVal != n:
            if curCount > maxCount: # check if current run > max so far
                maxVal = curVal      # store new max value
                maxCount = curCount  # store new max count
            curVal = n     # init the act ones
            curCount = 1   #  -"-

       # print (n, ":", curVal, curCount, maxVal,maxCount)

    # edge case - the max list is the last run            
    if curCount > maxCount:      
        maxVal = curVal
        maxCount = curCount

    return (maxVal, maxCount) # tuple of (value, number of occurences)

l = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2,2]

print(makeMyHomework(l))
```

Comment: makeMyHomework thats great name ;)))))))

Comment: I just stumbled over this and actually it wasn't for my homework ..

Comment: @Marcel Wow - thats a long time response :D - your question looked like a typical "do my homework" question. Just a task, no try to solve it yourself,  hence the function name I used. If it offends you, I'll  change it

Comment: Just saw this after 2 years, no its okay haha :D now looking at this question I totally would have assumed it's homework too! @PatrickArtner